# Updating a feature images not updated

Tags: 2010, feature, feature-upgrade

The systems team updated a feature for me. The feature added a new favicon and a new image. The new files added in my feature where not deployed to the style library. Existing files were updated. I have opend up the wsp and the files are in there. I have opend up feature.xml and the files are mentioned there. Why could my new files not be deployed?

Comment: Did you do an upgrade solution or retract/deploy?

Comment: To be honest I don't know (it was done by the system team). I asked them to do an upgrade (that is the command I use from VS2010).

Comment: You should try and confirm if they have used the Update-SpSolution cmdlet (or any other form of solution update). If that is the case, be aware that update DOES NOT provision any new file or module - this may explain why your *new* file is missing and old ones get updated.

Comment: Yes they used Update-SpSolution. How do i get it so new files are provisioned?

Comment: @John, please see my answer. Fell free to comment if you need further assistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments in your question it seems that the system team used the Update-SpSolution PowerShell cmdlet. In that case they are performing a solution *update* which won't work to provision any new artifact.

As discussed in [this other question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22006/does-update-spsolution-trigger-a-spfeature-upgrade/22008#22008) SharePoint supports two main ways to upgrade a solution:

- a retraction/readd cycle, also refered to as solution *replacement*
- a solution *update*

To be elegible for update a solution must fall in [a set of requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543659.aspx), one of them is that a solution update may not add any new artifact (file, module, feature etc) or change the identity of an existing file (for example, change the id of a feature or rename a file).

Since you need to add a new file, you are bound to use the solution replacement option - remove the old solution version and add the new one. A little warning: based on your specific solution contents you may need to deactivate some feature before retraction, reactivate some of them after deploy etc or other actions required for a clean upgrade process.

Comment: Looking more closley in VS2010 that is what it does when you do deploy.